# How to solve for a matrix when both it and its transpose are in the formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us say that we have `x'Cx=Z` and we need to solve for x. x is a vector where C is a symmetrical square matrix. I have no clue as to how to solve for x when I cannot simply isolate it and do not know where else to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take $C$ to be the $2\times2$ identity matrix, and $Z$ to be $1$. Then all you can say about $x$ is that if $x=(a,b)$ then $a^2+b^2=1$. In other words, there are infinitely many $x$ that "solve" your equation.

Answer (score 1):

$x^TCx$ produces a scalar, i.e. it is a function $\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$. As such, you can't really solve for $x$. Instead, $x^TCx=Z$, where $Z\in\mathbb R$, defines a $(d-1)$-dimensional surface.

Functions of the form $x^TCx$, where $C$ is real and symmetric, are known as (real) [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form). Specifically:
$$
x^TCx = \sum_i\sum_jc_{ij}x_ix_j
$$
which is a polynomial of purely quadratic terms. According to the spectral theorem for real symmetric matrices, $C$ is diagonalizable by an orthogonal matrix $Q$, so we can simplify to:
$$
x^TCx = x^TQ^T\Lambda Qx = \tilde x^T\Lambda\tilde x = \sum_i\lambda_i\tilde x_i^2
$$
where $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues of $C$. Since $Q$ is orthogonal (and we can choose it to have determinant $+1$), all we have done is rotate the space.

The surfaces defined by $\sum_i\lambda_i\tilde x_i^2 = Z$ are higher dimensional generalizations of ellipses and hyperbolas, including degenerate cases. See also [quadric surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric).